# Use CASE statement to test values in table 1, set values in table 2

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I am new to SQL, so if you could include in answer correct syntax (for PostgreSQL) that will be great.

I have two tables

table 1 "geo_temp", with columns [geo_type1] [geo_type2]....[geo_type6] [geo_typeR];

table 2 "geo_summary", with column [geo].

Here what I want to do,

```
CASE
WHEN (geo_type1 NOTNULL) THEN (geo = geo_type1)
WHEN (geo_type2 NOTNULL) THEN (geo = geo_type2)
...
ELSE (geo = geo_typeR)
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`coalesce()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html) function:

```
geo = coalesce(geo1, geo2, ...,geoR)
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value found in the list, which is what your intention is.

As an update statement:

```
update geo_summary set
geo = (select coalesce(geo1, geo2, ...,geoR)
  from geo_temp
  where geo_temp.id = geo_summary.id)
```

Comment: Thanks!  The coalesce works very well. I should mention geo_summary is an empty table. When I ran the UPDATE statement, I got message says "affected record 0." In this case, should I use INSERT? What will syntax look like?  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to use this in a `WHERE` or `ON` Clause.

You could do something like...

```
geo =
CASE
WHEN (geo_type1 is NOT NULL) THEN geo_type1
WHEN (geo_type2 is NOT NULL) THEN geo_type2
...
ELSE geo_typeR
END
```